# How to boolean subtract multiple overlapping instances from each other with geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have this object I've created via geometry nodes:
[image: object to be cut]

Now I want to do a boolean subtraction on each side of the object, so that when I'm done each side has angled edges that don't overlap with the other sides.  (Note in the supplied image each side overlaps into the adjacent ones which is not what I want.)

I'm rather new to geometry nodes and I've tried a bunch of ideas but have not been able to figure it out yet.  I can use Separate Geometry to pick a side, and then feed the selection and inverted selection (all the other sides) into a Mesh Boolean subtraction, but that leaves me with only noe side properly cut, but I need to do it for all sides.

I'm aware there are other ways to make this sort of shape, but this is a simplified version of my project and I really think I need to be able to do a boolean operation like I'm describing to get the results I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Mesh Boolean has an option to intersect with self, allowing to do do the *Union* operation in one pass:

[image]

If this doesn't work for you for some reason, this is an equivalent using a repeat zone (Blender 4.0) - you could put some additional logic for each step there:

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  I tried it but I must be doing something wrong.  I still get the same result where the edges overlap.  Lemme post a pic of me trying to copy what you did.

Comment: It looks like the mesh boolean doesn't do anything for me. 
 I'm on Blender 3.6.2.  https://imgur.com/a/UH8TJhS

Comment: Oh I should also note that I need each side to remain a separate object at the end (I think that means I can just exclude the Merge by Distance that you included?).